# Excluding files from coverage when using Karma and Istanbul

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner, istanbul, minmatch

I am using Karma to test my JavaScript and get coverage reports.  I am using the Istanbul coverage report, which is the default.  Here is my preprocessors parameter:

```
    preprocessors: {
        'framework/**/*.js':'coverage',            
        'framework/*.js':'coverage',
        '!framework/node/**/*.js':'coverage',         
        '!framework/test/**/*.js':'coverage',                                 
        'framework-lib/**/*.js':'coverage',
        '!framework-lib/tool-data-api/tool-data-api.js':'coverage'
    }
```

As you can see, I am trying to use the "!" as a negate command, which usually works with Node.  However, it is not working here and none of my directories are being excluded.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just do not write the patterns/files you do not want to be covered. Or in case you need to preprocess them, just not write `coverage` as preprocessor in the list (for each file you can either specify a string or a list of strings).

Comment: If you want to use the `!` to exclude paths it won't work: see this issue: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/440

Answer (score 7):

According to https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html:

> **/*.js: All files with a "js" extension in all subdirectories
>   **/!(jquery).js: Same as previous, but excludes "jquery.js"
>   **/(foo|bar).js: In all subdirectories, all "foo.js" or "bar.js" files

So, based on this, I tried the following:

```
preprocessors: {
    'framework/**/!(node|test)/*.js': 'coverage',
    'framework-lib/**/!(tool-data-api).js': 'coverage'
}
```

Which seems to have accomplished what you are looking for.

As a note to others who come here looking for how to target all files EXCEPT .spec.js files, try:

```
'**/!(*spec).js'
```

Which seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

In the Karma used minimatch.js lib for mathing files.
So you need rewrite you rules. 
For instance to exclude folder node node it should has

```
preprocessors: {
        'framework/*[!node]/*.js':'coverage',            
    }
```

Comment: minimatch.js uses extglob syntax which is the weirdest beast I've seen so far: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob

Comment: how would you ignore any node_modules folders?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are running "istanbul cover ..." to run your coverage report, but if you are, you can use the -x flag to exclude files/patterns.  Typing in "istanbul help cover" will show you usage including this.

```
 -x <exclude-pattern> [-x <exclude-pattern>]
              one or more fileset patterns e.g. "**/vendor/**"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directories /  file you want to exclude are not loaded by any other include. for example, 'framework/**/*.js':'coverage'  will load files you are trying to exclude in '!framework/node/***/.js':'coverage'

Comment: So how would you get ALL files from a directory EXCEPT `*spec.js` files?

Answer (score 0):

you can modify in `angular.json` under `test`->`options`

```
"codeCoverageExclude": ["src/testing/**/*"]
```